# why is gem still outdated after bundle update

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am working on a gem and it's on github.

When I include the gem in an application, do a capistrano deploy, and (on the server) run:

```
bundle outdated
```

I see:

```
 * authengine (0.0.1 d8baa49 > 0.0.1 de43dfa)
```

which tells me that a more recent commit is available. Why doesn't the bundle update (part of capistrano deploy) pull the more recent version? There is no version constraint in the Gemfile of the host application, and anyway they have the same version number, just different commits.

Even if I log into the server and run

```
bundle update authengine
```

I get the same "outdated" result afterwards.
What am I missing here?

Comment: are you committing your `Gemfile.lock` by any chance?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Matenia. I _was_ committing Gemfile.lock but I am not now, and it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: nah .. you should commit the Gemfile.lock where possible .. it makes sure you keep your gem versions in sync between dev and prod (providing there are no system-specific gems required), have you tried specifying the `:ref => 'de43dfa'` argument before running bundle update (just a suggestion to force it to use the right ref)

Comment: Thanks again, Matenia. Yehuda Katz in his blog is adamant that Gemfile.lock should not be under version control. And this is the advice too in the bundler documentation (probably written by Yehuda). I haven't tried specifying the ref, and that will probably work, but only this time... the moment the gem is updated, I'm stuck on the prior commit.

Comment: I was initially confused by the comments above, to keep or not to keep Gemfile.lock. If you're writing a gem DO NOT keep Gemfile.lock in version control. If you're writing an application ALWAYS keep Gemfile.lock in version control. Since the question is in regards to a gem ...

Comment: This article has some useful information about this exact problem https://olivierlacan.com/posts/why-wont-bundle-update/

Answer (score 19):

One thing I've found that can cause this is if other gems in the bundle make requirements on gems by version that are incompatible.  Bundler tries to reconcile these by selecting versions of gems such that their requirements can all be satisfied.  The result is that it quietly refuses to update gems.

The way to *check* this is to set an explicit version requirement in your Gemfile.  Something like

```
gem "authengine", "> 0.0.2" #(you'll need to bump the version to make this work)
#or
gem "authengine", :ref => "d8baa49"
```

Then run

```
bundle update authengine
```

You should see something like (this is taken from my particular case):

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "json":   In
>   Gemfile:
>       chef (> 10.8) ruby depends on
>         json (<= 1.6.1, >= 1.4.4) ruby
>
> ```
> logical-construct (>= 0) ruby depends on
>   json (1.7.5)
> ```

So, in my case it's a problem with explicitly requiring a newer version of json.

Comment: Thank you -- great info. I was really confused by this behavior, so I tried what you suggested and saw the same type of silent fail. I wish "bundle update" provided a little more feedback on these failures.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding manually setting the expected version to find out what is that generates the conflict.

Answer (score 3):

The author, André Arko, [stated](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3089#issuecomment-48540138) in 2014 that:

> The Bundler resolver is definitely a work in progress, and we adjust
>   the tradeoffs between specific versions and resolving quickly based on
>   user feedback.
>
> Bundler has consistently not provided the newest possible version of
>   every gem for the entirety of its existence, and it does result in a
>   lot of tickets being opened. In most cases, it turns out to be the
>   result of Bundler having to pick between the newest version of one gem
>   or a different gem, and Bundler picks the gem the user doesn’t care
>   about having the newest version of. That’s why it’s so important to
>   make your Gemfile version requirements accurately reflect your actual
>   requirements.
>
> I recognize that your assumption that Bundler would give you the
>   newest possible version seemed valid at the time, but the docs only
>   say that you will get a version that meets your requirements, not the
>   latest. Is there anywhere we could expand the docs to make it clearer
>   that the newest versions of everything simply isn’t feasible?

Comment: `the newest versions of everything simply isn’t feasible` do you mean algorithmically?

Comment: From the answer of Judson, I understand that this means that the dependencies between the gems means that some of them are holding some other back.

Answer (score 2):

What is the output returned when you run `bundle update authengine`? Does it actually say it updated the gem? Or does it ignore the gem?

You can try using the `--source` parameter to specifically tell Bundler to use the git repository. That, or your

```
bundle update authengine --source https://github.com/mustardseeddatabase/authengine.git
```

Also, when unexpected things like this happen, I like to clean up my gemlist in general. It could be that you still have older versions of the gem laying around, not using in bundler.

So you could do:

```
gem list
gem check
gem cleanup
```

Or do a complete reinstall

```
gem uninstall authengine
bundle install
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, JeanMertz. When I do bundle update. It says "Using authengine (0.0.1) from git://...etc. so it is using what's installed rather than fetching a fresh copy. I tried your other suggestions, too, without success. Thanks, though.